# Maintenance : File system vs Database

Tags: dbms, file-system

I'm comparing the advantages and disadvantages of File system (journaling and COW) and Database (SQL and Non-SQL). Not only from the developer's point of view, I also want to know further what are the challenges and difficulties in maintaining these two systems. Could you guys share your thoughts?

Comment: This is too broad of a question, it's like asking for a comparison of Microsoft Word and Gmail. Each tool / system has its use cases, and generally they're very different use cases. Please provide context on *what* it is you're trying to store. If it's data for an application, especially if *any* kind of manipulation / re-shaping needs to ever be done, or relating of that data between different kinds of objects, than a database is likely the option you should care about and not even consider a file system.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, if as a beginner, my response is incorrect.

But, I think you should use DBMS if the data you use requires frequent manipulation while simultaneously being able to view the previous entries.

Like storing it in Journaling/COW based File Systems, log becomes cluttered and due to frequent changes, it might be difficult to keep track of old entries .

Besides, dbms does offers more data security, constraints integrity, data recovery and ease of manipulating data representation based on user needs(without altering real data) .

If you use as a single user, then maybe its fine but on a centralised storage workstation, you wouldn't want another user to be able to access all the records.

Hence, I will prefer DBMS more for larger volumes of data which is constantly updated and frequented by multiple users in a day.